# MIME type in jsp

Tags: jsp

In jsp page directives we mentioned  contentType="MIME-Type", in this MIME means what?

Comment: Maybe he couldn't understand the topics from google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) is an Internet standard for describes message content types.

MIME messages can contain text, images, audio, video, and other application-specific data.

Official MIME info is provided by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)
http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Answer (score 4):

MIME means Multi purpose Internet Mail extensions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type and the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)